# Joining two tables having two same columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am making a school project with mysql database.

Having [this](https://i.gyazo.com/82a7fee6cd7e8efca2b7259101223ddd.png) table ready, I need to create a query that will join ReciverID and SenderID with accounts.Email column. I have tried many solutions, but all my atempts resulted into duplicates or errors. The result should look like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/472dce48b711a083303f024191954049.png).

I have table "accounts"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `AccountID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Email` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `Balance` DOUBLE(10, 5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
  `VerifyCode` INT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Email_UNIQUE` (`Email`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `VerifyCode_UNIQUE` (`VerifyCode`)
)
```

And table "transactions"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`transactions` (
  `TransactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SenderID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ReciverID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` INT(32) NOT NULL,
  `Note` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` DOUBLE(10, 5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TransactionID`),
  INDEX `Sender_idx` (`SenderID`),
  INDEX `reciver_fk_idx` (`ReciverID`),
  CONSTRAINT `reciver_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ReciverID`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`AccountID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `sender_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`SenderID`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`AccountID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Please post the code you have developed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try working with alias.

Something like

```
Select T.TransactionID, S.email, R.email, T.date, T.note, T.Amount 
From Transactions T, Accounts S, Accounts R
Where T.SenderID = S.AccountID AND T.ReceiverID = R.AccountID AND 
--The rest of your conditions
```

> PS: I wouldn't recommend naming a column date... It's a key word usually resulting in errors

**EDIT**

Base on @HoneyBadger comment the comma joining style is out dated... So here's another way to do it

```
Select T.TransactionID, S.email, R.email, T.date, T.note, T.Amount 
From Transactions T
Join Accounts S On T.SenderID = S.AccountID
Join Accounts R On T.ReceiverID = R.AccountID 
--add your conditions
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and for the recommendation!

Comment: Please don't teach people antiquated, comma separated, join style. `join...on...` Is the standard for 30-odd years, it's easier to write, easier to read and easier to maintain